# Update record with Entity Framework generating an Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I am working on application using Entity Framework, WPF, C# with a local sql-server database (two tables : Patient and MedicalSheet). while updating a record I have an exception that says :

A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

My DAL code looks like :

```
 public static void UpdatePatient(Patient patient)
    {

        using (context ctx = new context())
        {
            ctx.Entry(patient).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I have an update button for each row in the dataGrid, once clicking on it, it instanciate an new window that loads data from dataGrid into multiple textBoxes, the event handler of the update button looks like this :

```
private void EditInDatagrid_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new ModernDialog
        {                 
            Title = "Update patient DataGrid",
            Content = new EditPatient((Patient)patientGrid.SelectedItem){
            Width = 600,
            Height = 400
            },
        }.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The UserControl of the new update window (that pops-up after clicking the update button) code looks like :

```
 public partial class EditPatient : UserControl
{
    Patient patient = new Patient();

    public EditPatient(Patient patient)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        fNameBoxEditing.Text = patient.firstName;
        lNomBoxEditing.Text = patient.lastName;
             .....

    }


    private void ValiderEditing_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        patient.firstName = PrenomBoxEditing.Text;
        patient.lastName = NomBoxEditing.Text;


        PatientDAL.UpdatePatient(patient);

        MessageBoxButton btn = MessageBoxButton.OK;
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage("Patient infos modified succeeded!", "", btn);

    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem may be that you do not have the correct ID for the patient when attempting to save it. Can you use a breakpoint to check the patient ID in the UpdatePatient method?

Comment: Thanks for taking th time to answer, I just checked the Id = 0;

Comment: Gert Arnold : I did show the UpdatePatient method code, the context in Edit Patient was just testing a LINQ query but I removed it now from the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this.patient = patient into EditPatient constructor

Comment: Bro Just Thanks, I've been struggling to find a solution, it works perfectly, Big thanks.